# Unauthorized mount hd ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Hey, I am trying to mount my hd on ubuntu by I receive this message "No possible mount location - Not Authorized".

It happened after some upgrades on system, and the sound stoped too.

here is my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=34a80206-2142-427e-9c43-52aabbd28d81 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID="F0DE78CDDE788D9A" /media/sda2 ntfs-3g defaults,locale=pt_BR.UTF-8 0   0


#
#
#
```

In this case its sda2 which cant me mounted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try scrapping the locale option and see if it mounts.  Also, the UUID format doesn't look right to me.